# showing error -- addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JS+DOM</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Shopping List</h1>
        <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
        <p class="second">No Excuse</p>
        <ul>
            <button>Click Me!</button>
            <li class ="bold red"random="23">Notebook</li>
            <li>jello</li>
            <li>spanish</li>
            <li>rice</li>
            <li>birthday cake</li>
        </ul>
        
    </body>
    <script>
        var boton = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
        boton.addEventListener("click",res);
        function res(){
            console.log("Hello");
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

i am trying to show hello in console.in console its shows error addEventListner is not a function.so please help me to resolve this.

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName Return an array of button tag  so you need to provide an specific index  like "var boton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];"

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns the HTMLCollection, it will have multiple HTML nodes. So you have to loop through the objects or use as var boton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

Comment: @MayurAsodariya getElementsByTagName returns an array like object, so you would have to do "document.getElementsByTagName("button").item(0)" or use the from method to convert the collection into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `console.log()` in function to print what is getting returned from specific api or you can use `debugger` keyword to debug your script.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JS+DOM</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Shopping List</h1>
        <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
        <p class="second">No Excuse</p>
        <ul>
            <button>Click Me!</button>
            <li class ="bold red"random="23">Notebook</li>
            <li>jello</li>
            <li>spanish</li>
            <li>rice</li>
            <li>birthday cake</li>
        </ul>
        
    </body>
    <script>
        var boton = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
        /* if you have multiple button, you can loop over elements as getElementsByTagName returns an array*/
        boton[0].addEventListener("click",res); // this will fix the error
        function res(){
            console.log("Hello");
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through the HTMLCollection returned by getElementsByTagName. Addeventlistener only works on a single element.

```js
var boton = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
boton.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", res));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it will solve your issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>JS+DOM</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Shopping List</h1>
      <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
      <p class="second">No Excuse</p>
      <ul>
         <button >Click Me!</button>
         <li class ="bold red"random="23">Notebook</li>
         <li>jello</li>
         <li>spanish</li>
         <li>rice</li>
         <li>birthday cake</li>
      </ul>
   </body>
   <script>
      document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
        if (Element.prototype.closest) {
          if (e.target.closest('button')) {
            console.log('hello')
          }
        } 
      });
   </script>
</html>
```